# ORA-01722: invalid number for explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to execute this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALLPOSITIONS
IS
CURSOR C IS
SELECT *
FROM TRKEMPLOYEE
ORDER BY SUBSTR(NAME, ' ');
BEGIN


FOR TRKEMP IN C
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('testing');
/*
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRIM(TRKEMP.NAME));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRIM(TRKEMP.NAME) || ':' || CHR(10)|| TRKEMP.DOB);
*/
END LOOP;


END ALLPOSITIONS;
/
```

but it keeps giving me ORA-01722: invalid number, what is going on?

Comment: The second parameter of `substr()` has to be an integer...

Comment: With issues like this, it's worth testing the SQL on its own to narrow down the problem. In this case it was `SUBSTR(NAME, ' ')`, and not related to cursors or PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```sql
ORDER BY SUBSTR(NAME, ' ')
```

The [`SUBSTR` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) has the signature:

```
SUBSTR( string_value, start_position, [substring_length] )
```

So, it is expecting a number in the second argument; `' '` is not a number.

If your `NAME` column contains `firstname lastname` and you are trying to `ORDER BY` the last name then use the `INSTR` function to find the position of the first space character:

```sql
ORDER BY SUBSTR( NAME, INSTR( NAME, ' ' ) + 1 )
```

Comment: oh, what if i want to find the position of the second space?

Comment: @Astoach167 Here is the documentation for [`INSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSTR.html#GUID-47E3A7C4-ED72-458D-A1FA-25A9AD3BE113); it has an `occurrence` argument.